# jQuery DatePicker validation and Firefox

Tags: firefox, datepicker

I've recently changed my datepicker to take the format of "dd-MM-yyyy" however the validation is coming back as not valid in firefox however it works fine in chrome.

Any ideas? This was working but now not....

Firefox version: 32.0.2